# Mage::getStoreConfig('Section/Group/Field') path not in core_config_data

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, system.xml, core-config-data, system-config

The error after turning developer mode back on is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in /home/vimarket/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463
```

Within the system.xml of the extension, these fields are causing the issue:

```
<pixenable translate="label">
                      <label>Enable</label>
                      <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                      <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                      <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                                                    <comment>Activate this plugin</comment>
                  </pixenable>

                                    <tipe translate="label">
                      <label>Tracking Type</label>
                      <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                      <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_tracktype</source_model>
                      <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                      <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </tipe>
```

They're within the  tags.  So, the paths of these must not be there, but I can't figure out exactly where the paths should be.

Config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <PixelMarket_Pixel>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </PixelMarket_Pixel>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <pixel>
        <use>standard</use>
            <args>
              <module>PixelMarket_Pixel</module>
              <frontName>pixel</frontName>
            </args>
        </pixel>
    </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                   <pixel>
                        <file>pixel.xml</file>
                   </pixel>
            </updates>
        </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <pixel>
          <class>PixelMarket_Pixel_Helper</class>
        </pixel>
    </helpers>
      <blocks>
         <pixel>
               <class>PixelMarket_Pixel_Block</class>
         </pixel>
      </blocks>
      <models>
         <pixel>
               <class>PixelMarket_Pixel_Model</class>
                 <resourceModel>pixel_mysql4</resourceModel>
         </pixel>
         <pixel_mysql4>
               <class>PixelMarket_Pixel_Model_Mysql4</class>
                 <entities>
                        <reftable>
                                <table>reftable</table>
                        </reftable>
             </entities>
         </pixel_mysql4>
      </models>
      <resources>
         <pixel_setup>
               <setup>
                   <module>PixelMarket_Pixel</module>
               </setup>
               <connection>
                   <use>core_setup</use>
               </connection>
         </pixel_setup>
        <pixel_write>
              <connection>
                  <use>core_write</use>
              </connection>
        </pixel_write>
        <pixel_read>
              <connection>
                  <use>core_read</use>
              </connection>
        </pixel_read>
      </resources>
  </global>
  <admin>
       <routers>
          <pixel>
             <use>admin</use>
               <args>
                   <module>PixelMarket_Pixel</module>
                  <frontName>pixel</frontName>
               </args>
          </pixel>
       </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
       <menu>
          <pixel module="pixel">
                <title>Pixel</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <reftable module="pixel">
                        <title>Manage Reftable</title>
                          <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                          <action>pixel/adminhtml_reftable</action>
                    </reftable>
                </children>
          </pixel>
      </menu>
       <acl>
          <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                           <pixel translate="title" module="pixel">
                                <title>Track Customer</title>
                                <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                                   <children>
                                     <reftable translate="title">
                                            <title>Manage Tracker</title>
                                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                     </reftable>
                                   </children>
                          </pixel>
                    </children>
                </admin>
          </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
           <updates>
                 <pixel>
                     <file>pixel.xml</file>
                 </pixel>
          </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: Have you been to the admin page for this extension and actually saved the options?

Comment: I can't get to the admin page for it at all. There's a tab at the top to manage a table of information (it's a customer tracking extension), and then there're additional options on the left side panel in System Configuration where you enable it and such. That's the one that I can't get to. If I take the system.xml off the server, I can access the admin panel's main System Config page. If I put it back on the server, sometimes I can (only on Chrome, never on Firefox). But I have yet been able to access the actual options for the extension without getting the HTTP Error 500 page.

Comment: if it's a paid extension ask their support. reinstall the extension and if it is working then your edits are incorrect, if not, then the extension is rubbish and you should ask for support or money back. otherwise, your question is off-topic here

Comment: Their support is nonexistent. I even contacted CodeCanyon (where I purchased it) to tell them that their support is lacking. I've emailed the personal email they gave, as well as their "support" email. I've tried contacting them via their website, and their contact form is bugged and doesn't let you send anything. I always come here as a last resort if paid support is no help.  If there's no obvious error from what's seen, then wouldn't stating that be more helpful than stating that the extension is rubbish or the question is off-topic?

Comment: Check your logs to find out what is causing the 500 error. A common problem is that the helper for this module is missing.

Comment: After turning developer mode back on via index.php, this is the error I'm getting: 

Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in /home/vimarket/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463

Edited original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from:

```
 <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_tracktype</source_model>
```

This source model does not exist. There is also no other source model in the core, called "tracktype", so it's unclear to me what they are trying to do here. A custom source model should not be added to the `Mage_Adminhtml` namespace but to the extension namespace.

Conclusion: It's a bug in the extension, their `system.xml` is wrong.

Comment: So if I placed tracktype.php in Pixel/Model/Adminhtml/System/Config/Source, and changed the source model to pixel/system_config_source_tracktype, would this work?

Comment: @taskle Yes, exactly, though I find this module to be quite dubious in terms of quality. Can you share a link?

Comment: Would the class within the tracktype.php be changed from

    `class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Tracktype`

to 

   `class Pixel_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Tracktype`

?

@benmarks http://codecanyon.net/item/magento-customer-tracker/5656303 was purchased

Comment: *"Would the class within the tracktype.php be changed... to `Pixel_...`"* That's the ticket, mate ;-)

Comment: So, I'm receiving this error:

`Warning: include(PixelMarket/Pixel/Model/System/Config/Source/Tracktype.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/.../public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93`

I would assume I need to add something further to my config.xml as well? Do I need to define the model? (My current config.xml is posted above)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the difference in model group name and module. Change the classname and path according to that error message.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create Tracktype.php file into this file path Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Tracktype.php

Add below code into system.xml file

```
                  <tipe translate="label">
                  <label>Tracking Type</label>
                  <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                  <frontend_model>YOURMODULENAME/adminhtml_system_config_source_tracktype</frontend_model>
                  <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                  <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                  <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                  <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </tipe>
```

Comment: Creating a file within the core to mask the problem? That's a bad idea. Also how would you know what to put inside?

Comment: The file is currently in the core (how it was in the original extension), so I assume @Magikvishal means within the custom module's Block directory? Then using <frontend_model>? I think